# VMware WorkStation guest VM can see unicast traffic for other VMs

Tags: vmware, wireshark, virtualization, vmware-workstation

I have VMware Workstation 15.5 Pro installed on Windows 10 laptop, with 4 guest VMs. I ran wireshark from one of the guest VMs and I could see unicast traffic from other VMs (kindly ignore broadcast & multicast traffic for now). Kindly see the screenshot below:

```
Host 10.20.20.1
VM1 10.20.20.13 (Win10 VM with wireshark)
VM2 10.20.20.99 (Linux VM)
VM3 10.20.20.240 (Server-2016 VM with DNS role)
VM4 10.20.20.250 (Linux VM)
```

[image: screenshot here]

This means there is zero isolation. How is this possible and how can I prevent this behavior?

Comment: @baldr, thanks for editing the question. I do not have enough privilege to embed images.